# Spring boot service global error handler, global exclude log4j

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, spring-boot

I have problems with setupping logging in service based on spring-boot.
As per [spring logging docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-logging) I have following dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        .......
        <!-- global exclude -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

So I expect to use logging provided by `spring-boot-starter-logging` and exclude other transitive dependencies on log4j.
I've created a global error handler that uses `org.apache.log4j.Logger`, as exception arises on my local machine I see the stacktrace, but on dev server this doesn't happend. Below is my error handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GlobalErrorHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void onError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        String params = req.getParameterMap().entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey()+ "=" + Arrays.toString(e.getValue())).collect(joining(";"));
        LOGGER.error("Error on path: " + req.getRequestURI() + ", with parameters: " + params, ex);
    }
}
```

As I understand spring-boot-logging has diff logging dependencies, and if I use excluded log4j in global error handler it should use for example slf4j adapters, so I won't need to modify existent codebase.

Would you please clarify this ?

EDIT:
Also on dev server I have strange output from log4j that says that for some class in one of my dependencies no appenders was found:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.company.dependency.SomeClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Do you want to use log4j instead of logback?

Comment: @AliDehghani I want to use logging provided by spring-boot and exclude lo4j that used as a transitive dependency for service dependencies

Comment: and do not make changes to service code that already uses log4j